# Choose which folders appear on start (menu) setting via group policy

Tags: group-policy, windows-10, settings, start, user-settings

There is a number of switches available under a setting in windows 10 called "Choose which folders appear on Start". I find them very handy but by default only Settings is switched on. I would like to be able to modify this default setting and push it out to other users on the domain via a GPO. I have scoured the administrative templates folder on GP to find a setting that does this in both computer and user configuration but have come up with nothing.

- Is this settable by an administrative template?
- Is it set by a registry entry?
- Is it built into the NTUser.dat registry hive as an entry?

The domain uses roaming profiles and mandatory profiles. Any suggestions as to where I can find them?